# popover and title tooltip at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button and when I place the mouse over it I want to see the "title" message but the problem is when I add a popover I can't see the title message anymore!
Basicly this is the code that stops the tt

```
$('#somebutton').popover({
    html: true,
    title: '<div class="tooltip-info-title" lang="en"> ... <button type="button" class="close tooltip-close" onclick="$(\'#somebutton' + '\').popover(\'hide\')">x</button></div>',
    content: function () {
        return '<div class="tooltip-body" lang="en">'... '</div>';
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) gives you an example of how to format your HTML to get Popover to work properly. The `title`-attribute is what's going to be displayed in the popover.

Consider the following JS:

```
$('#somebutton').popover();
```

And the following HTML:

```
<button id="somebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-info" title="This is the title" data-placement="bottom" data-content="This is the popover body" data-trigger="hover">This is a button with a popover</button>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ysxrth9/)

Answer (score 0):

Let This help you.

```
$('#popbutton').popover({
        html: true,
        title: "Example",
        content: function () {
            return $('#popContent').html();
        }
    });
```

You can popover any html content using id/class of html element with html() function

```
<button id="popbutton">Click</button>
<div id="popContent" class="hide">This <em>rich</em> <pre>html</pre> content goes inside popover</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kAYyR/